# Fill list from joined table LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using ViewModelsDemo.Models;  

namespace ViewModelsDemo.ViewModels  
{  
    public class CustomerViewModel  
    {  

        public List<JoinedTableClass> JoinedTable { get; set; }  
    }  
    public class JoinedTableClass
{

    public string FirstField { get; set; }  // Table1
    public string SecondField { get; set; } // Table2
    public string ThirdField{ get; set; }  // Table 2


}

}
```

I tried to do the following, but it's not working.

```
        var customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel  
        {

            JoinedTable = (from Cust in Tables.Customer

            join D in Tables.Dep on Cust.Customer_ID equals D.ID

            select new CustomerViewModel  { Cust.FirstName , Cust.LastName , D.Serialz })

        };

        return View(customerViewModel);
```

On the before-last line, I have the following error:

> **Cannot initiate type "CustomerViewModel" with a collection initiliazed because it does not implemented System.Collections.Ienumerable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Changing your Implementation
 If you just want list of JoinedTableClass,then use this

```
            var JoinedTable = (from Cust in Tables.Customer
                  join D in Tables.Dep on Cust.Customer_ID equals D.ID
                 select new JoinedTableClass
                 {
                   FirstField = Cust.FirstName ,
                   SecondField = Cust.LastName ,
                   ThirdField = D.Serialz 
                 }).ToList()



        return View(JoinedTable );
```

Comment: I actually tried that before, but that didn't help. I get this whenever I compile

`System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication2.JoinedTableClass]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication2.CustomerViewModel'.`

Which from searching, I believe it has something to do with the `@model WebApplication2.CustomerViewModel` on the top of my View... but I still can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.JoinedTableClass>